# Yiddish version of "Tov Li Toras Picha"

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry, yiddish, simchat-torah

In various shuls during Hakafos on Simchas Torah, I have heard the well known song "Tov Li Toras Picha" (טוב לי תורת פיך מאלפי זהב וכסף" - תהלים קיט עב") with a chorus in Yiddish. Does anyone know the words of this verse? Also, what is the origin of this song?

Comment: I was just singing this...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-b6ygKvaFU Is this it?

Comment: https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%A2%D7%91

Answer (score 2):

טוב לי תורת פיך מאלפי זהב וכסף

"The Torah of your mouth is better for me than thousands of gold and silver." (Tehillim 119:72)

עס איז בעסער צו לערנען די הייליגע תורה מער ווי אלע גאלד און זילבער

(Yid.) It is better to learn the Holy Torah, more than all gold and silver.

Comment: Added translation :)